# Javascript encoding decoding problem

Tags: javascript, encoding

I have the following javascript

```
 var cst = "\x26";
 var other = $("#D1").html();
```

And my html has D1 div like the following

```
 <div id="D1">\x26</div>
```

Now when I add a breakpoint and see my two variables cst and other. One is shown & and another \x26.
Also

```
cst.length == 1
```

but

```
other.length == 4
```

I am confused. I need the value of other to be same (&) and I cannot change the Div.
I am also using JQuery so I can use $(div_id)

Answer (score 1):

HTML does not use Javascript-style escape strings.

Your `<div>` actually says `\x26`, not `&`.

Comment: Then how can I convert it back to & in Javascript again? I cannot change the Div and I need output as &

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
var other = eval( "'" + $("#D1").html() + "'" );
```

Comment: Thanks. It works. But I am not in favor of eval. I will select this if I don't get any other working answer.

Comment: Use the text content (`text()` in jQuery) not `innerHTML`/`html()` which will have extra HTML-encoding applied. `JSON.parse` is safer then `eval` where available. You may want to check that there's no unescaped quote or newline in the string before `eval`ing it otherwise.